# Is there any way to get callback from redis at interval of 1 minute after set the key

Tags: node.js, redis

If I set the hash key using Redis npm as below

```
client.hmset(
    ["key", "test keys 1", "test val 1", 
     "test keys 2", "test val 2"], function (err, res) {
});
```

then is there any way to get a callback at every 1 minute to check the existence of the key.

Comment: There may be a Node way to do that, but Redis doesn't offer this natively

Answer (score 0):

`redis` lib does not have this feature, but you can integrate with the generic `setTimeout` function

```
client.hmset(
    ["key", "test keys 1", "test val 1", 
     "test keys 2", "test val 2"], function (err, res) {
        setTimeout(function() { /* do something */ }, 1000)
});
```